# sql formulate proper query

Tags: sql

I have a complicated database structure for which I'm trying to formulate a sql query. First the structure of the tables:

```
Table ANIMALS:
+---------+--------+
|    id   |  name  |
+---------+--------+
|    1    | Tiger  |
|    2    | Lion   |
|    3    | Cat    |
+---------+--------+


Table ANIMAL_ATTRIBUTES:
+---------------+-----------+
| attribute_id  | animal_id |
+---------------+-----------+
|            10 |         1 |
|            11 |         3 |
|            12 |         3 |
+---------------+-----------+



Table ATTRIBUTE_TEXT:
+--------------+-- ----------+
| attribute_id |    value    |
+--------------+-------------+
|           10 |  black      |
|           11 |  big        |
|           12 |  tail       |
+--------------+-------------+


Table INFORMATION:
+---------------+-----------+
| attribute_id  | filter_id |
+---------------+-----------+
| 10            |    20     |
| 11            |    21     |
| 12            |    22     |
+---------------+-----------+


Table FILTER:
+-----------+-----------------+
| filter_id | name            |
+-----------+-----------------+
|    19     | First           |
|    20     | Second          |
|    21     | Third           |
+-----------+-----------------+
```

The ATTRIBUTE_TEXT.value needs to be checked for a corresponding FILTER.id and the ANIMAL with this value should given as result (additional fields don't matter).
So far I got this:

```
select * 
from FILTER as f join INFORMATION as i ON (f.filter_id = i.filter_id) 
                 join ATTRIBUTE_TEXT as at ON (i.attribute_id = at.attribute_id) 
                 join ANIMAL_ATTRIBUTES as aa ON (at.attribute_id = aa.attribute_id)
                 join ANIMALS as a ON (aa.animal_id = a.id) 
where (f.filter_id = 20 and at.value like '%black%');
```

which should give me the 'TIGER' as animal.name.

The problem is that I have more Filter.id 's to check with a corresponding ATTRIBUT_TEXT.value:
e.g.

```
Filter 1:
Filter.id = 20 and ATTRIBUTE_TEXT.value = 'black'
and
Filter 2:
Filter.id = 21 and ATTRIBUTE_TEXT.value = 'big'
```

which should only return as result 'CAT' if both are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `OR` with proper parantheses:

```
select * 
from FILTER as f join INFORMATION as i ON (f.filter_id = i.filter_id) 
                 join ATTRIBUTE_TEXT as at ON (i.attribute_id = at.attribute_id) 
                 join ANIMAL_ATTRIBUTES as aa ON (at.attribute_id = aa.attribute_id)
                 join ANIMALS as a ON (aa.animal_id = a.id) 
where 
(f.filter_id = 20 and at.value like '%black%')
OR
(f.filter_id = 21 and at.value like '%big%')
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be AND instead of OR?

Comment: No, when the where clause is applied on a row, the column filter_id can not be 20 AND 21 at the same time. It's either this or that. Therefore it has to be OR.

Comment: @tombom Ok, you're right that anding filter_id = 20 and filter_id = 21 doesn't make sense. But shouldn't the query then join with filter two times, once for each predicate provided by the user? Because, if I understand your query correctly, it will return all animals that are either black or big, whereas it should return only animals that are both.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the question then. In that case you are correct and one has to join to filter a second time. On the other hand the OP accepted my answer and said that it works. I'll add the other solution in case he changes his mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to return 'CAT' and it must be 'big' AND 'black' both, you should add additional animal attribute (`INSERT INTO ANIMAL_ATTRIBUTES SELECT 10,3`) and use query like this:

```
select aa.animal_id
from FILTER as f join INFORMATION as i ON (f.filter_id = i.filter_id) 
                 join ATTRIBUTE_TEXT as at ON (i.attribute_id = at.attribute_id) 
                 join ANIMAL_ATTRIBUTES as aa ON (at.attribute_id = aa.attribute_id)
                 join ANIMALS as a ON (aa.animal_id = a.id)
where 
(f.filter_id = 20 and at.value like '%black%')
OR
(f.filter_id = 21 and at.value like '%big%')
GROUP BY aa.animal_id
HAVING count(aa.attribute_id)=2
```